# Jump from controller C to controller A but not show mid page

Tags: ios, xcode

In my rootViewController, i will check condition A to show "A page" or not,

And I also can enter "C page" form main page.

when user is disconnect in C page, 
I will

- dismiss C page
- then enter main page
- main page check condition A to show A page

but, i don't want to show main page, I just want to show A page, how should I modify my code?

page struct :

```
rootPage -----------  C Page
      |
      |
      --------------  A Page
```

root.controller

```
- (void) viewDidAppear {
    if (condition A) {
        [self persentViewcontroller:"A page"];
    }

}
```

C Page.controller

```
- (void) userDisconnect {
     [self dismissVC];
}
```

In C Page, dismiss function, app will show main, then present A page!

how can I just show A page, without show root page!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do as follow might be help you.

```
   for (UIViewController* viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[YOUR_CLASS_NAME class]] ) {
           YOUR_CLASS_NAME *YNC = (YOUR_CLASS_NAME*)viewController;
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:YNC animated:YES];
            return;
        }
    }
```

Similarly you can dismiss controller also.

Comment: But rootView and Page C is not in the same navigation controller, I try to use `presentingViewController` to dismiss controller, but i still have use conditionA to decide present page A or not! I add page struct in my post, maybe it will make more clearly!

Answer (score 0):

C Page.controller

```
- (void) userDisconnect {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:mainPageController animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:APage animated:YES]; 

}
```

Comment: Actually, my controllers are not in the same navigation controller, and root/pageA is not navigation controller,  this may not work for me!  but Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much `Objective-C`, so I write in `Swift`. Add a segue from A to C Page.controller

```
func userDisconnect(){
performSegue(withIdentifier: yourseguename, sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Yes, if I just show new pageA, it works, but when I dismissviewController pageA, page C still there, I think stack looks like{rootView, pageC, pageA},
I try to dismiss rootView in pageA, but it still show pageC, I have no idea about that!

Answer (score -1):

instead of - (void) viewDidAppear  you may write the condition on - (void) viewWillAppear and see the difference

Comment: I've try, but it will cause some system warning `presentviewcontroller whose view is not in the window hierarchy`, and also will show root page first, I think its not a good solution.

Comment: can you show code in dismissVC so that we can help you accordingly

Comment: just `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`